# Error al compilar en C. Incompatible type for argument 1 of

Tags: c

Al intentar compilar, en C, el código publicado C sale el error `"Incompatible type for argument 1 of 'mostrarCarton'`

No se como solucionarlo y tampoco puedo pegar todo el código acá, ya que es muy extenso.

```
void menu(int cartones, int naleatorios,struct Carton c){
    int opcionMenu = 0;

  do
    {
        printf("\nIngrese 1 para mostrar los cartones\n");
        printf("Ingrese 2 para sacar las bolas \n");
        printf("Opcion : ");
        scanf("%d", &opcionMenu);

        switch(opcionMenu)
        {
        case 1:
        {
            if (cartones==1)
            {
                printf ("\n\n--------- Cartones en juego ---------\n\n");
                mostrarCarton(c.carton1, cartones);
            }
            if (cartones==2)
            {
                printf ("\n\n--------- Cartones en juego ---------\n\n");
                mostrarCarton(c.carton1, cartones);
                mostrarCarton(c.carton2, cartones);
            }
            if (cartones==3)
            {
                printf ("\n\n--------- Cartones en juego ---------\n\n");
                mostrarCarton(c.carton1, cartones);
                mostrarCarton(c.carton2, cartones);
                mostrarCarton(c.carton3, cartones);
            }
        }

        break;

        case 2:
            generarBolas(naleatorios);
            break;
        }
    }
    while(opcionMenu!=0);

}
```

La declaracion de la función de `mostrarCarton` es:

```
void mostrarCarton (struct Carton c, int cartones);
```

Y la implementacion es la siguiente:

```
void mostrarCarton (struct Carton c, int cartones)
{
    int i,j;
    printf ("\n\n");
    for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", c.carton1[i][j]);

            printf("%d", c.carton1[i][j]);
            printf("%d", c.carton2[i][j]);

            printf("%d", c.carton1[i][j]);
            printf("%d", c.carton2[i][j]);
            printf("%d", c.carton3[i][j]);
        }
        printf ("\n\n");
    }
    printf ("------------------------------");
}
```

La estructura ´Carton´ es la siguiente:

```
struct Carton {
    int carton1[RENGLON][COLUMNA];
    int carton2[RENGLON][COLUMNA];
    int carton3[RENGLON][COLUMNA];
};
```

La función `menu` está declarada de la siguiente manera:

```
void menu(int cartones, int naleatorios, struct Carton c);
```

En el caso de que necesiten mas código, avísenme, todo lo que necesiten lo iré editando, estaré muy al tanto y también actualizare si hago algún cambio, como lo hice recién eliminando algunas declaraciones que no servían, Muchas gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

Saludos

Comment: ¿y cómo declaras *mostrarCarton*? ¿Y cuál es la defición de *Carton*? No podemos responder sin los datos de lo que envías y  lo que se espera que envies.

Comment: Claro SJuan, el problema es que StackOverflow no me deja publicar tantas lineas de codigo si no escribo en el post, ahi agrego esos datos

Comment: @SJuan76 hay alguna web donde yo pueda poner mi código y ustedes lo visualicen? como tiene twitter, etc.

Comment: Hatori Hanso Deverias poder editar el post sin ningun problema.
Recuerda que cuanta mas informacion aportes y mas detallada mejor.

Comment: Pon la información **relevante**. Revisa como hacer un [mcve]

Comment: @SJuan76 Ahi edite el post, espero pueda servirte, Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Puede ser que te dé un error porque no le llegan los argumentos correctamente a void menu( )?
Creo que la estructura no hace falta que la pongas en los argumentos de la función void menu( ), sino que funcionan globalmente.
https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_en_C/Estructuras_y_Uniones

Comment: Puedes aportar la funcion main( )?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El mensaje de error te dice que hay incompatibilidad de tipo en el primer parametro de `mostrarCarton`, que esta declarado así:

```
void mostrarCarton (struct Carton c, int cartones);
```

indica que, siempre que se invoque `mostrarCarton` el primer parámetro debe ser una estrucutura de tipo `Carton`; pero cuando lo invoca en la funcion `menu` lo está haciendo así:

```
mostrarCarton(c.carton1, cartones);
```

En el ámbito de la función `menu` el identificador `c` es un parámetro de tipo `Carton` y por lo tanto `c.carton1` es de tipo `int[RENGLON][COLUMNA]` (según la definición de `struct Carton`). Ahí está la incompatibilidad de tipo, no puede convertirse `Carton` en `int[RENGLON][COLUMNA]`. La invocación correcta en la función `menu`, en las 6 sentencias que se invoca, debería ser

```
mostrarCarton(c,cartones);
```